# Autohotkey: Require Capslock for Hotstring

Tags: autohotkey, capslock

The following autohotkey code

```
:*:\alpha::α
```

results in the hotstring text "\alpha" being continuously replaced by the corresponding UTF8 char "α".

However, it would be quite annoying to always have this replacement enabled. So I figured to activate it via the CapsLock key. So how do I enable the above hotstring only when the CapsLock key was pressed immediately before the string combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
; The tilde prefix (~) prevents AHK from blocking key-down/up events.

~Capslock Up:: Send, {Capslock Up}


; The #If directive creates context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstrings:

#If (A_PriorHotkey = "~Capslock Up")

    :*:\alpha::α

#If
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm

Comment: if you want to write the scripts with notepad, you can Change the script a little bit `:*:\alpha::
SendInput {U+0251} ;Send Unicode symbol alpha
return`   [UnicodeTable](https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=alpha)

Comment: This worked. However, the Capslock is still in effect then! I solved this by adding "SetCapsLockState AlwaysOff" and this solved it for me. Thanks! : )